# Convert object to array in MongoDB Document

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I am trying to convert a mongoDB documents object into an array with the same data.
I have a document structured like this:

```
{
    _id:"43434",
    fistname: 'Bob',
    lastname: 'Toto',
    address: { city: "cityName", postalCode: "000000", streetName: "streetname" },
}
```

And I want to restructure my data like this :

```
{
    _id:"43434",
    fistname: 'Bob',
    lastname: 'Toto',
    address: [{ city: "cityName", postalCode: "000000", streetName: "streetname" }],
}
```

How would I go about achieving that?
Can I use the **$project (aggregation)** of mongo?

Comment: If you wanted to write results back to collection then aggregate won't help you -unless if you're on version <4.2. prior versions has $out but I wouldn't prefer as it's destructive coz it will overwrite collection with new data, You might see address converted to array with value as null (this happens if you don't have address in first place) !! Please check the above link it should help you or if you're in v4.2 use $merge in aggregation !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
db.tester.aggregate(
   [
       {$match:{"_id":ObjectId("5db06342f079fa02a63adaf8")}},
      {
         $project: {
            fistname: 1,
            lastname:1,
            address: [{ city:'$address.city','postalCode':'$address.postalCode',streetName:'$address.streetName'}]
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Please try this query